# ion-nav-view with nested ion-nav-view not working

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a strange problem with `ion-nav-view` nesting. When I load the application in a browser, I can see the URL is getting changed to `/app/menu`, but no contents from `menu.html` appear on the page. The page is blank.

Following is the code snippet

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="starter">
 <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.
    state("app", {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/default.html",
    controller: "AdaptiveController"
  })
    .state("app.menu", {
    url: "/app/menu",
    views: {
      "page-content": {
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
        controller: "MenuController"
      }
    }

  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/menu");
})
```

**default.html**

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-nav-view name="page-content"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**menu.html**

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-positive bar-header" align-title="center" no-tap-scroll="true">
        <div class="buttons buttons-left header-item">
            <span class="left-buttons"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive header-item">Welcome</div>
        <div class="buttons buttons-right header-item">
            <span class="right-buttons"></span>
        </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
       <ion-item class="item item-icon-left">
         <i class="icon ion-person"/>   
         <h3>Profile</h3>
       </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

If I change the code in `default.html` to following it works.

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-view name="page-content"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Does than mean ion-nav-view either need tab or ion-side-menus? Can't it work with ion-view?

Answer (score 1):

Try change the code:

```
.state("app.menu", {
url: "/app/menu",
views: {
  "page-content": {
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: "MenuController"
  }
}
```

to

```
.state("app.menu", {
url: "/menu",
views: {
  "page-content": {
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: "MenuController"
  }
}
```

in hrefs continue write #/app/menu